# How to group and label a repeating variable in R

Tags: r, grouping, repeat

I have a data frame that has 2 variables, time and phase, where phase is the phase of breathing.
I need to be able to group "insp" and "exp" to create a breath number.
The length of each phase is not set and can vary from breath to breath.
The lengths of each insp and exp are not equal.
The actual df has > 30,000 rows so I can't do this by hand.

An example would be:

```
tibble(time = c(1:35), 
       phase = c(rep("insp", each = 5), 
                 rep("exp",  each = 10), 
                 rep("insp", each = 8), 
                 rep("exp",  each = 12)))
```

But I'd like it to look like this...

[image: Desired result]

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rle` :

```
df$breath_num <- paste0('b', with(rle(df$phase == 'insp'), 
                        rep(cumsum(values), lengths)))
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly I just have to make sure each group always starts with an "insp" breath.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version with `rle`

```
df$breath_num <- with(rle(df$phase), paste0("b", rep(ceiling(seq_along(values) / 2), lengths)))
```